MIPS Assembly - Finding the Value of a Sequence
.data

   var: .byte  0xF0, 0xE1, 0xD2, 0xC3, 0xB4

.text
   la     t0, var
   lb     s0, 2(t0)
   li      s1, 0x88888800
   sb    s1, 3(t0)

What is the value of s0 in hexadecimal at the completion of the sequence?
I thought that the value is 0xD2, but apparently that is not right.
Can anyone explain this to me?

You can run this yourself in a simulator like MARS and single-step it.  Have you looked up lb in  MIPS manual?  It's a sign-extending load, unlike lbu which zero-extends, so it can't produce 0x000000d2 because the high 24 bits don't match bit the top bit of the low byte.

0xD2, interpreted as a signed byte, is -46.  So, that's what will be in the register: -46 as a 32-bit value.

Storing 0x88888800 as a byte to memory is a red herring, as only the 00 will be stored to memory.  sb silently truncates the value to 8 bits before storing, since it is a byte-sized store to memory.
